# pipenv sync and pipenv install --system --ignore-pipfile in docker environment

Tags: python, docker, pip, pipenv

According to [pipenv official documentation](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

> **sync**
>
> pipenv sync [OPTIONS]
>
> Installs all packages specified in Pipfile.lock.
>
> **install**
>
> pipenv install [OPTIONS] [PACKAGES]...
>
> Installs provided packages and adds them to Pipfile, or (if no packages are given), installs all packages from Pipfile.
>
> --ignore-pipfile
> Ignore Pipfile when installing, using the Pipfile.lock.

Is it safe to assume `pipenv sync` and `pipenv install --ignore-pipfile` are identical without any hidden drawbacks?

***More background**: I was using --system flag to install the python packages to the system since I don't care about isolated environments in a docker container. However --system flag is unavailable for `pipenv sync` (See [github issue](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2227)), so I figured `pipenv install --system --ignore-pipfile` might be a viable hack.*

Comment: totally agree `sync` should have `--system`. that would clear up much confusion for using the lock file in a container where you don't need a virtualenv.

Comment: For interested readers: `pipenv sync --system` now works as of pipenv 2020.11.4 (PR https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/pull/4441)

Answer (score 17):

you can see the notes in [Advanced usage of pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#using-pipenv-for-deployments)

> `pipenv install --ignore-pipfile` is nearly equivalent to `pipenv sync`, but `pipenv sync` will never attempt to re-lock your dependencies as it is considered an atomic operation. `pipenv install` by default does attempt to re-lock unless using the `--deploy` flag.

so maybe `pipenv install --ignore-pipfile --deploy` equal to `pipenv sync`

Answer (score 7):

Not really an answer (I'd be interested in confirmation as well) but for what it's worth, we've been using

```
pipenv install --system --deploy --ignore-pipfile
```

in our Dockerfile with good results.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether it was added after you posted this question, but [the documentation](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced.html#using-pipenv-for-deployments) does address this very question (although, to be fair, it's kinda of a "uh?" type of explanation for me...)

FWIW, I believe that `sync` should have the `--system` flag too (I'm trying to address the very same issue as you, of building a container, and do not want to maintain **two** separate files: `requirements.txt` for the container's system Python, and `Pipfile` for my dev virtual env).

Your "hack" seems to me currently the only viable option.

Answer (score 1):

You could just go with

```
pipenv install --deploy
```

It achieves the same and you can add the `--system` flag, although you'd better not.

There is no real harm on using a python virtual environment inside a docker image, but there are some subtle benefits. Pipenv now recommends against system-wide installs https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/pull/2762